# Link Directly to an Open Modal with Multiple Modals

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple modals in a page and these modals opens when I click in then.

But they **don't generate links**

I want them to have **their own links**, for example:
wwww.mywebsite.com/test#myModal1

I've tried without sucess at least 30 codes avaible on internet

Each of my modals use the same Javascript code, with just some little differences

For example, here is the code that I use on my fifth modal

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "block";
}

btn[4].onclick = function() {
    modal[4].style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span[0].onclick = function() {
    modal[0].style.display = "none";
}

span[4].onclick = function() {
    modal[4].style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. do not use hash;
2. instead hash use the search: `www.yourwebsite.com?openmodal=modal1`;
3. your code will be simplest:

```
// modal dialog opener
const openModalDialog = (modalId) => {
  const modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// callback
const openModal = () => {
  // parse search part in url "openmodal=modal1"
  const search = {}
  console.log('openModal#11111')
  window.location.search.split('&').forEach((item) => {
    const [key, value] = item.split('=')
    search[key] = value
  })
  // so, you can now find modal id from your url if its passed:
  const modalId = search.openmodal
  // and, if id is passed - do a something to open modal:
  if (modalId) {
    // your code for open modal here
    openModalDialog(modalId) 
  }
}

// add callback to document onLoad event:
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", openModal)
window.addEventListener("load", openModal)
```

it is all. When you open url `www.yoursite.com?openmodal=myModal5` - modal with id `myModal5` will opened after page load.

Comment: Thanks Sergio,
I know nothing about JS, what are exatcly that changes that I need to make on your code?

Comment: for example, you have id = 4, url: www.yoursite.com?openmodal=4 then, your code for openModal function will be: `modal[modalId].style.display = "block";` see the updated comment code above.

Comment: I've tried for days without sucess. Modals still without url. My code is something like that https://codepen.io/FelipeNS/pen/jJjGMJ

Comment: try this url: https://codepen.io/SergioBelevskij/pen/eXwLgL?editors=0010&openmodal=myModal5 - (`https://codepen.io/SergioBelevskij/pen/eXwLgL?editors=0010&openmodal=myModal5`)